# Swift Realm remove object from user list

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to remove an object from a user list but keep the original value inside the database.

My user has a list of favourites which are `let favourites = List<Element>()` and these are objects within the database stored locally. When I come to remove the object from the user list its removing the element from the Database not just the reference to the object.

Here's what I'm currently trying which crashes the application on removing:

```
fileprivate func toggleFavourite(element: Element) {
        let favs = realm.objects(Element.self)
        if let fav  = favs.filter("uuid == %@", element.uuid!).first {
            let index = favs.index(of: fav)
            try! realm.write {
                user!.favourites.remove(at: index!)
            }
        } else {
            try! realm.write {
                user!.favourites.append(element)
            }
        }
    }
```

I was originally trying which deleted the object from the database:

```
try! realm.write {
     user!.favourites.delete(element)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: @chirag90 - its a standard realm crash non descript due to trying to remove from a strong referenced object with `remove(at: index!)` using the delete method works but actually deletes the entire object - not the users reference to it.

Comment: The deletion method is actually correct. I see you're force-unwrapping a couple of times here, maybe that's what's crashing?
Try to safely-unwrap ```user``` and ```index``` and see if it helps.

Comment: @Starsky - The user and index would both exist in this case so force unwrapping is ok (You would never even hit this method if user or index didn't exist). The deletion method whilst correct also removes the object. I've decided to map the favourite to another object instead of relying on a link to an existing.

Comment: @user7684436 ```...which crashes the application on removing``` - that's why I supposed it might crash because of that, since you never provided an exact crash message.